# update service property from isolated scope angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I modify value of service from isolated scope?

in my code, I want to change the default date to something else, by the service property .

my directive :

```
app.directive('ExampleDirective',['myService',function(myService){
return {
       restrict: 'E'
       templateUrl: '/path/to..'
       scope : { currentDate: "=" ,
                 lastDate : "="
               }

    link : function (scope,element,attr){
    var date = scope.lastDate;
    scope.$watch('currentDate',function(newDate,oldDate){
           LastDate.defaultDate = newDate ;

}

    }  


    }]);
```

and my simple service :

```
app.factory('LastDate',function(){
return {
      defaultDate : new Date()
}

});
```

Comment: Link is not the right place to do it. I prefer to do this with controller. If you have issues use assignation within $scope.$apply(function(){assign here}). It us a known issue.

Comment: what the difference between write this function on link or in the directive'scontroller ?

Comment: No difference. Controller runs first and link second. More link runs once

Comment: Link will not clash but if two way binding is not happening and you want to run digest cycle you are stuck since $scope.$apply will not trigger watches and digest correctly

Comment: There are two ways to approach this . make a function in your factory that assigns a new date and in the controller call watch and call the function of the new date assignation of factory and loop the watch function in timeout

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Not good since you will be creating watches for every second or so. Second approach is call new date() when you need it. It will give that time anyways and while doing some activity assign the  new date to your model or service variable